# drawing Histogram with 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, histogram

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import xlrd
import xlwt

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Scatter plot.xlsx')
sh1 = wb.sheet_by_name('T180')
sh2=wb.sheet_by_name("T181")
sh3=wb.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

x= np.array([sh1.col_values(7, start_rowx=50, end_rowx=315)])
x1= np.array([sh2.col_values(1, start_rowx=48, end_rowx=299)])

y=np.array([sh1.col_values(2, start_rowx=50, end_rowx=299)])
y1= np.array([sh2.col_values(2, start_rowx=48, end_rowx=299)])

print x

plt.hist(x,bins=50)
plt.xlabel("dx (micron)")
plt.ylabel("dy (micron)")
plt.show()
```

As you can see the figure from link is obtained by this code. Why this histogram is like this?

[image]

How can I solve it? Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: what do you not like with this figure? It looks ok to me, there are just not many values in your array.

Comment: Thanks. But why it is not like this way (link)? Data number is same here (about 300) http://www.filedropper.com/figure2 @dnalow

Comment: Can you show the data?

Comment: It looks different because you have a smaller number of bins in the figure of your second link. The smaller the bin width, the less events they will contain..

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/scatterplot @HYRY, thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of `x` is `(1, 265)`, it's a 2-dim array, you need to convert it to 1-dim array first:

```
plt.hist(x.ravel(), bins=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was working nicely according to the suggestions by HYRY. Thank to @ HYRY.

```
 plt.hist(x.ravel(),bins=100,histtype="step",label="Before Translation")
```